# Proper function notation for matrix functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, multivariable-calculus, notation

For a vector-valued function we have the notation $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$.

**Is this also a proper notation for a matrix function? Are there any conventions?**

> For a matrix of one variable, $t$, 
>   \begin{align}
> \mathbf A(t)=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> a_{11}(t) & a_{12}(t) & \cdots & a_{1n}(t)\\
> a_{12}(t) & a_{22}(t) & \cdots & a_{2n}(t)\\
> \vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
> a_{n1}(t) & a_{n2}(t) &\cdots & a_{mn}(t)
> \end{bmatrix},
> \end{align}
>   is it correct to write $\mathbf A:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^{m\times n}$?
>
> And for a matrix of several variables $\mathbf x=(x_1, \dots, x_n)$,
>   \begin{align}
> \mathbf B(\mathbf x)=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> b_{11}(\mathbf x) & b_{12}(\mathbf x) & \cdots & b_{1n}(\mathbf x)\\
> b_{12}(\mathbf x) & b_{22}(\mathbf x) & \cdots & b_{2n}(\mathbf x)\\
> \vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
> b_{n1}(\mathbf x) & b_{n2}(\mathbf x) &\cdots & b_{mn}(\mathbf x)
> \end{bmatrix},
> \end{align}
>   is the proper notation $\mathbf B:\mathbb R^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{m \times n}$?

Answer (score 5):

It's correct as long as you define $a_{ij}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ or $b_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, and you describe how you are identifying the set of $m\times n$ matrices with $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

You can avoid this if you define $M_{m\times n}$ to be the set of all $m\times n$ matrices with real entries, and set $A:\mathbb{R}\to M_{m\times n}$ and $B:\mathbb{R}^n\to M_{m\times n}$ as above. Then the functions $a_{ij}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $b_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ are given by
$$
a_{ij}(t) = (A(t))_{ij}
\quad\text{and}\quad
b_{ij}(x) = (B(x))_{ij},
$$
where $E_{ij}$ denotes the entry in the $i$th row and $j$th column of $E\in M_{m \times n}$.
This is the technique that I've seen used.